# C# Mock Setup Return depends on sequence of other method executions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have am Mocking a method and telling it to return something when called:

```
mock.Setup(imp => imp.GetDataSegment()).Returns(customDataSegment);
```

However, if `GetDataSegment()` is called before the method `NextDataSegment()` then it should return nothing. It should only return something if `NextDataSegment()` is called first.

How can I achieve this?

I'm trying not to make assumptions about how the implemented code will use the two methods together but it should be something like this:

```
while(class.NextDataSegment()){
    DataTable segment = class.GetDataSegment();
}
```

Comment: What actually determines whether `GetDataSegment()` or `NextDataSegment()` is called first in the code being tested? Can you show that code?

Comment: @devNull updated with an edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a good solution would be to setup your methods in the following way:

```
bool wasCalled = false;
mock.Setup(imp => imp.NextDataSegment()).Returns(() =>
                {
                    //logic here
                     wasCalled = true;
                });

mock.Setup(imp => imp.GetDataSegment()).Returns(() =>
            {
                if (wasCalled)
                    return customDataSegment;

                return null; //Or default value, etc.
            });
```

Comment: I would say [callback](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks) is a little bit more appropriate way to handle first part.